# How to create a new column that contains the row average in a data frame?

Tags: r, average

I'm a freshman learning R, and I am stuck on some homework.

Data frame:

```
student HW1 HW2 EXAM1 HW3 HW4
A       100 95  80    96  100
B       98  100 89    100 100
C       90  95  90    88  90
```

My question is how do I create a new column that contains the `homework average`? This new column should be the last column and aligned to each student.

The apply function, grep function and `rowMeans` may be used in this assignment.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1$hwavg <- rowMeans(df1[,grep("^H",names(df1))])
```